# Image Path in Rails 4

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, heroku

I've recently deployed a project on Heroku and fixed most asset pipeline issues such that my stylesheets and javascript files work. However, I have one line of code in a css file that I thought would work based on documentation and other stackoverflow topics:

```
background-image: image-url("giphy.gif");
```

I got that line directly from another stackoverflow solution, given that my original code was simply url("giphy.gif"). Loading the page with either code gives me a 404 in the console. The project is structured like a rails app, so the app->assets folder has:

- images

  - giphy.gif
- stylesheets
- javascript.

I've tried asset-url, image-url, url, "images/giphy.gif", "giphy.gif". Many iterations have been tried. I figure this should be a simple switch, but I'm not sure what I'm missing. Would appreciate all assistance! Thanks

**Update:**

Error message: GET https://herokuappname.herokuapp.com/assets/giphy.gif 404 (Not Found)

I even tried just moving the gif so that it lies in the assets folder instead of the images subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

Try `background-image: url('giphy.gif');`

Comment: That was the syntax I had used in the first place to no avail

Answer (score 0):

**Background images declared in CSS must be in a `.css.erb` file, `application.css.erb,` for example.**

I've found this syntax works:

```
  background-image:url('<%= asset_path("giphy.gif") %> ');
```

But again, it must be in an `.erb` file in order to properly reference the asset pipeline.

Good luck.

Comment: I edited the file-name to be .css.erb, updated it in the config/initializer/assets precompile, and still couldn't get the image to load with either your syntax or any of the ones I'd already tried

Comment: It's hard to guess. Diff Rails versions have different helpers.  I would advise using the web browser console. Do you see the fingerprinted image filename or  "giphy.gif"? You have it right when the the fingerprinted filename is in the rendered html. Until then, it won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried manually

`heroku run rake assets:precompile`

Then pushing again?

Is your master branch on git up to date? Have you pushed to git `git push origin master`, then `git push heroku master`

Just listing some things I would try